# Outlook Ribbon: button toggle in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, toggle, imagebutton

I have written a listener in vba, inside my outlook, to perform an action when I receive a mail.

I would like to be able to turn this feature on and off using a button on my Outlook ribbon.

To know the current state (on/off), I would like to toggle between two images on the button (green/red).

Does anyone know how to alter the image on the button when it has been clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this specifically, or if it's even possible, but you can edit a Group's visible property at runtime. You could therefore have two groups, with two images - one red, one green. In this case, I have a group called Actions, and I will show how to make it visible/invisible:

XML - Place your button as a control in here

```
<group id="customGroup1" label="Actions" getVisible="CallbackGetVisible">

</group>
```

Public/Module level declaration. This will determine whether the group is visible or not

```
Public bShowActions As Boolean
```

CallbackGetVisible is called by the XML to set the visible property of the group. The visibility is determined by bShowActions

```
Sub CallbackGetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)
On Error GoTo err_Handle
Const strError As String = "'CallbackGetVisible'"

    'Don't Re-Set The Value If It's Already The Same
    If bShowActions = visible Then GoTo Cleanup
    visible = bShowActions
    GoTo Cleanup

'Set Any Objects to Nothing, Exits Routine
Cleanup:
    Exit Sub
'Throw Error
err_Handle:
    'Handle your error here
    Resume Cleanup
End Sub
```

It's not straightforward, but you should be able to achieve what you need.